# Why the integration of a chain representing the fundamental class of a closed oriented hyperbolic manifold is the volume?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Reading a book I've encountered this affirmation:

Let $M$ be a closed oriented hyperbolic manifold, $[M]$ the foundamental class generating $H_n(M,\mathbb{Z})$, $\alpha$ a n-chain in $C_n(M)$ representing $[M]$ and $\omega$ a volume form positively oriented.

We have that $\int_M\omega=\int_\alpha\omega$

There isn't any further explanation, but I have no idea of why this is true.

Comment: Well (in simplicial homology at least) a nice enough chain representing $[M]$ is just an oriented triangulation of $M$, so this should be true on any compact oriented manifold.

Comment: Yea, but that's one chain. But it's true for any chain, even with coefficients different from 1, so I'm still missing something

Comment: But by Stokes theorem, the integral $\int_\alpha \omega$ does not depend on the chain $\alpha$ you choose to represent the homology class.

Comment: Oh, ok, well, I guss I've to go read up a bit more about it: any suggestion for a good source?

Comment: Not really, sorry - I'm only passingly familiar with algebraic topology.

Comment: Ok nevermind, thank you anyway for the help ;)